# Database table for password recovery via email link

Tags: sql, database, authentication, password-recovery

I am working on a authentication system.
It has two tables

**UserRegistration** // used to store user information temporarily till user verifies email

```
ID 
-UserRegistrationID
-FirstName
-LastName
-emailId
-password
-dateTime
-activationCode
```

**AuthenticatedUsers**// System users

```
-AuthUserID
-FirstName
-LastName
-emailId
-password
-dateTime
```

Noe I have to provide the option to recover password via email. I have to sent user a recovery link.

Where to store the recovery link code in database? Should I create a separate table for recovery code:
**RecoveryCode**

```
-recoveryID //PK
-AuthUserID //FK
-recoveryCode
-dateTime     //as the link is valid only for 24 hours.
```

Please provide your feedback and suggestions. 
Thanks!

Comment: Simple answer would be "YES"

Comment: Use recoveryCode in AuthenticatedUsers table, for example. Usually there is no need for separate tables like UserRegistration and Authenticated users. Use only Users instead.

Comment: This Q asks for opinionated answers and thus it has a chance to be closed as such. Nevertheless...Another option is to encode all necessary stuff within a query path and don't use any extra tables. Of course, path shall contain some control sum to prevent accidental access to other accounts and all relevant parts shall be obfuscated.

Answer (score 5):

In my application, the recoverycode is stored within the other user information.

It is just a token which is valid only one time. If the users click the recovery link, he can change his password. The recovery token is reset on every password change (which needs for authenticated users still the current password).

But **most important**, the recovery token should be **stored like the password**, that means, with a strong hash method. The created token (I use UUID4) is sent to the user (as part of the link) and stored hashed in the database.

The link needs the token and something unique to the user (I found the user id totally okay) for this. There is no need for multiple recovery links for one user. So just save the one token you have with the other user data.

Source and further thoughts: [palco.readthedocs.org](http://palco.readthedocs.org/en/latest/passwords.html#password-recovery).

Comment: what do you think about a new table (lets call it tokens) with this columns: id, token, userId, createdAt.